# Why does my Perf Mon Logical Disk Counters for C and D are the same?

Tags: windows, perfmon

I have been gathering performance counter of 1 of our busiest server and hopefully analyze it after a week long data gathering. To my dismay, when I reviewed all the Logical Disk Counters of drive C and D the where just the same.

Here is my data collector setup

[image]

Based on the definition of this counters there should be a big difference because the D is where the oracle database files reside, it should have a more activity spikes and more average values compared to drive C.

Drive C counters result

[image]

Drive D counters result

[image]

See the Avg. Disk Bytes / Write counter, both the same.

Can you please advice what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Your Performance Monitor is showing the same details for both, i.e. the total across ALL drives and not just for the C: drive on one graph and the D: drive on the other. I have configured similar and got the same results.

What I have found is that if you add \LogicalDiks(C:)* to the data collector then you do not get the counters for the C: drive but the total across all drives. However if you add each of the individual Logical Disk Counters that you are interested in then you do get them for the selected drive, e.g.
\LogicalDisk(C:)\% Disk Read Time
\LogicalDisk(C:)\% Disk Time
\LogicalDisk(C:)\% Disk Write Time
\LogicalDisk(C:)\% Free Space
\LogicalDisk(C:)\% Idle Time
\LogicalDisk(C:)\Avg. Disk Bytes/Read
\LogicalDisk(C:)\Avg. Disk Bytes/Transfer
e.t.c

This is the same for the Physical Disk counters.